# Why is the series "Trigun" titled as such?

Tags: trigun

I recently learned of the series [*Trigun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigun) and, though I haven't started watching it yet, it seems quite interesting.

However, I'm curious about its title. "Tri-" seems to indicate "three", so I'd say the title meant either "three guns", or "gun with three parts" (like three barrels). However, I've only managed to find images of the main character [holding one gun](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HMDZrZhBJY8/UDBP336DbEI/AAAAAAAABjk/a3S7i_P5qZ4/s1600/Trigun.jpg), or [occasionally two](http://loadpaper.com/large/Trigun_wallpapers_155.jpg), and nothing sticks out about them having three of anything.

Without spoiling too much of the plot's sensitive points, can someone explain why the series is called *Trigun*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not related to the number of barrels of a gun, but the number of guns Vash has.

1st: Is the silver 45 named **45 LONG COLT AGL FACTORY**. This is the one we all see him carry.

2nd:

> the hidden gun inside his arm that we see in Episode 12 [image]
> This hidden gun also gets upgraded into a machine gun in episode 19.

3rd:

> the transformation of his arm into the **Angel Arm** that we see in Episode 16 [image]